# How to persist CSS changes with Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a drop-down menu.  I don't have access to the website just yet so I'm trying to find a solution through Google Chrome Developer Tools which I can test and then apply to the site when I get access.  It's only CSS and perhaps some Javascript changes.

The problem is I want to apply some new CSS style rules through dev tools, but then have these persist upon refreshing the web page.  Is there a way I can apply styles and get them to persist?  I've looked at the resources section, which kind of suggests I can do something like this (maybe by adding a local style sheet as a resource?), but I just can't figure out how to do it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Many thanks folks...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions.  I tried both but had minor issues with them (just not particularly easy or intuitive for me personally).  Instead I sumbled upon [Tincr](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tincr/lfjbhpnjiajjgnjganiaggebdhhpnbih), which I found to be a better fit.  Thanks folks.

Answer (score 12):

You can install the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) chrome extension, which is greasemonkey for chrome, and you can load userscripts that can **alter css** and **use jquery to modify the page**, and this changes are **permanent** as the script will be loaded and execute it automatically anytime you go to the site you set in the `@match` rule, see the following *userscript* which just changes the background color of the page:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       yourscript
// @namespace  http://yeeeee/
// @version    0.1
// @description  Change bacground color of page
// @require    http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @match      http://yourtargetsite.com/*
// @copyright  2012+, Me and Brothers
// ==/UserScript==

(function () {
    $(document).ready(function(){
        style = '<style type="text/css"> body {background-color: #CC7777 ! important;} </style>';
        $('head').append(style);
    });
})();
```

Comment: In my opinion,this way is the best way and it works very well.

Answer (score 10):

Since Version 65 of Chrome this can be done without plugins. In the developer tools go to the **Sources -> Overrides** tab and select any local folder, where chrome should save your persistent changes to. For changes in the DOM tree, use the **Sources** and not the **Elements** tab.

For a list of local overrides go to **⠇ -> More tools -> Changes**.

More info [here](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/01/devtools#overrides).

Comment: Note that you must check the "Enable Local Overrides" box after selecting a folder.  Otherwise, this should be the approved answer!

Answer (score 5):

My favorite tools for CSS overriding is Stylish https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe

It's useful for debugging and enhancing any web page. There is also a large library of existing styles, with a convenient link to them from the extension menu. Like these, for [StackOverflow.com](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/stackoverflow)

Answer (score 1):

Try the extension [stylebot](http://stylebot.me/about) that allows you to quickly create and save persistent custom CSS for sites.

Comment: Their website is down, but the extension is still very popular. You can find the source and the Chrome Extension link on https://github.com/ankit/stylebot

Answer (score 0):

There's also an extension called [hotfix](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hotfix/bfmckmhcljhakgkngnfjhmmffaabdafi?hl=en). It lets you save changes from Chrome Dev Tools directly to GitHub.